# Java Map anti-pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, list, oop, dictionary

**Edit:** I've gotten a couple of answers that say what I already said in the question. What I am really interested in is finding corroborating reference material.

---

I am looking at a code sample that more or less follows this pattern:

```
Map<String, List> getListsFromTheDB() {
  Map<String, List> lists = new HashMap<String, List>();

  //each list contains a different type of object
  lists.put("xList", queryForListOfXItems());
  lists.put("yList", queryForListOfYItems());

  return lists;
}

void updateLists() {
  Map<String, List> lists = getListsFromTheDB();
  doSomethingWith(lists.get("xList"));
  doSomethingWith(lists.get("yList"));
}
```

My feeling is that this is an anti-pattern. What the coder should have done is create a class which can be returned, like this:

```
class Result {
  private final List<X> xList;
  private final List<Y> yList;

  public Result(xList, yList) {
    this.xList = xList;
    this.yList = yList;
  }

  public List<X> getXList() { xList; }
  public List<Y> getYList() { return yList; }
}
```

This would be more type-safe, avoid over-generalizing a very specific problem, and be less prone to errors at runtime.

Can anyone point me to any authoritative reference material which specifies that you should avoid this kind of pattern? Or, alternately, if it's actually a good pattern, please give justification.

Comment: Note, there are always two types of lists returned; it doesn't vary by usage.

Comment: What you are saying sounds reasonable in your particular case because you always know that an input to `doSomething` is the xList and yList. But if you just wanted to process the returned lists in bulk without referring to each individual one it would indeed make sense to return some kind of a Map/List/Set structure.

Comment: I'd consider that an antipattern, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I think the point is the number of Lists is **fixed**. Since you ensure the code uses 2 lists, the map is a little bit over-generalizing.

So '*class Result*' is better I think.

Answer (score 4):

I say it depends on the context.

If you return a map, the caller has to know the 'magic' keys `"xList"` and `"yList"` to get the actual data out of the map. I mean magic as magic constants. (You could iterate over the map to find the magic keys, but that's just a trick.) By using the map you have actually hidden the data, making it harder to get what one wants (x- and yLists).

The magic constants do not have to be so magically. If `"xList"` and `"yList"` would be the table names in the database (or whatever external strings), then I would expect to get a *mapping* from table names to object lists. Someone might add/rename/delete tables. (Or, maybe prettier, I would like to be able to query per table like `getListFromTheDB("xList");`. )

In your code you got this method

```
queryForListOfXItems();
```

That does smell like hard coded xList and yList. That would thus (IMO) make a map a bad choice.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify what I'm looking for

Comment: @RMorrisey - Magic number (or constant) is a antipattern, so this style begs for one. But I don't know if there is a 'map antipattern'. Maybe now there is ;)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you.
Obviously the guy was lazy and used a Map to avoid creating a new class.
The side effect is that the code that need to use getListsFromTheDB() will be less readable, and, as you mentionned, more error-prone.

Of course, there is the alternative in which the caller creates the lists:

```
void fillFromTheDB(List<X> xList, List<Y> yList) {
  //each list contains a different type of object
  xList.addAll(queryForListOfXItems());
  yList.addAll(queryForListOfYItems());
}

void updateLists() {
  List<X> xList = new ArrayList<X>();
  List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<Y>();
  fillFromTheDB(xList, yList);
  doSomethingWith(xList);
  doSomethingWith(yList);
}
```

Comment: Edited the question to clarify what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any authoritative material, but my gut feeling is that, unless there's something more complex going on in the real code, using a `Map` this way doesn't bother me.  The `Result` class feels a bit like overkill, actually.

Comment: Doesn't it bother you that the compiler won't catch you if you type "xlist" instead of "xList"? In my actual code, these two methods are in different classes in different packages. You could fix this by using a constant, but really, why introduce the potential problem point in the first place?

Comment: I guess it does, a bit.  Thinking about it some more, I'd really rather just see two methods, getXListFromTheDB() and getYListFromTheDB().

Comment: I agree that it would be cleaner to use two separate methods in the example, but I think that's beside the point. =)